# Generic Type with another generic Type

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Im struggling with the following problem.

I've got a class named `FilteredCollection` which has two generic arguments.

- `CollectionSourceModel`
- `CollectionFilterObject`

The `CollectionFilterObject` also requires a generic argument which equals the `CollectionSourceModel`. This looks like the following snippet:

```
class FilteredCollection
    <
        CollectionSourceModel: CollectionItem,
        CollectionFilterObject: CollectionFilter<CollectionSourceModel>
    >:
    Collection<CollectionSourceModel>,
    CollectionFilterDelegate
 {
      let filterHandler: CollectionFilterObject
 }
```

And allows me to create subclasses like the following:

```
class TheatreFilter: CollectionFilter<TheatreItem>
{
     // some filter stuff
}

class TheatreCollection: FilteredCollection<TheatreItem, TheatreFilter>
{
     // some collection operations
}
```

This doesn't show me an error in the code but leaves me with an compiler error:

```
Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11
```

Is my pattern evil is there a better way to solve this?

Comment: Yes, this is almost certainly over-complicated for the problem, and seems to be relying heavily on subclassing, which tends to fight Swift. There are a lot of good ways to build things like this, but it's not clear what your constraints are. Why is there a Collection that isn't Swift's Collection type? Why are filters objects rather than just predicates (closures that return bool)? Why does the "CollectionItem" type exist? Is it really necessary? A small sketch of the problem should lead to a much better solution that doesn't require all this subclassing.